# Changing database storage engine later on?

Tags: mysql, storage, innodb, myisam

Suppose i have an existing site with a good user base and active content.  Suppose the tables for this database primarily use use Myisam storage engine.

However, later on i want to shift some of these tables to use InnoDb storage engine(most probably Innodb for performance as site has both reads and writes).

Is this possible?

How much of a work would this be and how complex?

How much time it might take and what are the pros and cons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No effort at all:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: i was expecting a bit more explanation about the impcat of this change though :)  didn't think it was this simple.